# Bold not showing in the screenfonts in LyX!

Tags: lyx

I have a weird LyX problem: Bold not showing in the screenfonts in LyX! Does anybody know how to fix that?

[image: Bold text does is not shown in bold!]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which font do you use?

Comment: I tried multiple. The standard ones (Times New Roman, Helvetica, Courier New - all with and without new.), then different versions of different fonts, e.g., Verdana, Trebuchet, etc.

Comment: You have to load the corresponding package.

Comment: @Bernard No, this is about the LyX GUI, not the PDF.

Comment: The PDF shows it fine...it's really the GUI!

Comment: I have no idea what could cause this, but have you tried something as simple as reinstalling LyX? I would also think anyone trying to answer this are interested in OS and LyX version. If no one here can give any hints, try at the LyX users mailing list.

Comment: @J.R.Peters  But you tried to change all these fonts in Tools > Preferences > Screen Fonts, not in Documents > Settings... > Fonts. Right?

Comment: Yes, of course, Fran! @Rest: Yes, it's a duplicate with the bug, I could not find the other bug report!

Comment: I have the same problem on different stations

Comment: The newest version of LyX solves the problem in principle! However, for some files you need to change the screen font.